# How to read values from a word doc file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Can anyone tell me how to read values from a word.doc file using VBScript. I had given a sample.doc file below.

```
Parameters              Default Values
-----------------------------------------------------
No of values            8192 
Sampling Frequency      12800
Frequency Hop           2000
No of times             2
```

The above one is given in a table.

Comment: Are these values inside a table? Or is is just a plain text?

Comment: what values??Could u plz make it more clear??

Comment: These Links should help<br>
[Word object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(VS.80).aspx) [Document Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some notes.

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Visible = True

wd.Documents.Open "C:\Docs\Tables.doc"

For Each t In wd.ActiveDocument.Tables
    s = s & "Table" & vbcrlf
    For i = 1 To t.Rows.Count
        For Each c In t.Rows(i).Cells
            s = s & Replace(c.Range.Text, vbCr & Chr(7), "")
        Next
        s = s & vbcrlf
    Next
Next

MsgBox s
```